# CiviMail unique sender cause problems with spam filters

Tags: civimail, spam

When I try to send a mailing, the spam filter detects new users (taken from the unique address) and prevents them from sending out.

Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Do you mean the 'from' address is different or new recipients?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out to be a setting in the outgoing spam filter. One of the rules is to check for new email addresses. If there are many, this may be a problem. But civi creates the email addresses for replies and bounces.